# SwiftUI: how to keep font colours in top edge area?

Tags: swiftui

I use a custom black background in an app so I am using this code to ignore the SafeArea

```
   var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.backgroundColor
//                vertical  only for bg  color but how do I keep
//                the color of the font ?
                
               .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
```

all is fine in dark mode

[image]

but in light mode the time, antenna and battery are invisible
[image]

is there a way to still keep the custom background on the top area but have the time, battery etc. in white even if the user is using light mode ?

Comment: e.g. VStack { }.preferredColorScheme(.dark) will keep your view colorscheme in dark mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose **.preferredColorScheme**

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {...}
      .preferredColorScheme(.dark) // white tint on status bar
}

var body: some View {
  ZStack {...}
      .preferredColorScheme(.light) // black tint on status bar
}
```